# SQL Converting bytes to INT and BIGINT

Tags: sql, sql-server, int, sql-server-2016, bigint

Can someone explain the exact reason why a conversion of the same bytes to INT and BIGINT in SQL yields vastly different results?

A small example that I've used:

```
SELECT '00T1p000029eYmpEAE' AS OriginalString,
   HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '00T1p000029eYmpEAE') AS HashedString,
   CONVERT(BIGINT, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '00T1p000029eYmpEAE')) AS IntValue,
   9223372036854775807 AS BigIntMax,
   CONVERT(INT, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '00T1p000029eYmpEAE')) AS BigInteValue;
```

So far I have found this:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1349851-391-1.aspx
but unlike the OP there, it is unclear to me what is happening in the conversion process.

Using MS SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016 - updated the question as well.

Comment: SHA-512, as the name implies, yields a 512 bit hash (64 bytes). That's not going to fit in either a `BIGINT` or an `INT`. If you convert both values back to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, you'll see SQL Server truncates the values by simply taking the least significant bytes (`0xEA936AAB39BCC918` for `BIGINT`, `0x39BCC918` for `INT`). Interpret these values as two's complement integers and there you go.